# Checkbox with Result from Database in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have a record fetch from database based on a dropdown selection.The result is shown as a table, in which the user is expected to tick his choice.After the selection,the user clicks a button which will automatically add his selection to a table.Now the issue is: the id that is fetched for each item changes when the button is clicked by turning it to ascending number.see image below:[image]

For instance, in the table below, id 773,774,777,895 and 901 are selected.When Add to Float Button is cliked, the Id now becomes: 773,774,775,776,777(arranged ascending). See code below:
for Displaying Table

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $r['item_code'];?>" name="itmcode[]"  readonly="readonly"/></td>
    <td><?php echo $r['description'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r['qty'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r['price_per_qty'];?>
    <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $r['total_value'];?>" name="tvalue[]" readonly="readonly" /></td>
    <td><?php echo $r['preferred_supplier'];?></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkbx[]"  value="<?php echo $r['id'];?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="gid[]"  value="<?php echo $r['id'];?>">
</tr>
</table>
```

Processing Script:

```
<?php
if(array_key_exists('chkbx', $_POST)&&(!empty($_POST['chkbx']))&&(isset($_POST['floatBtn']))){
    foreach($_POST['chkbx'] as $rec=>$value)
      {
        $itm = $_POST['itmcode'][$rec];
        $tval = $_POST['tvalue'][$rec];
        $t = $_POST['gid'][$rec];
        $apno =$_POST['aNo']; 
        $fno = $_POST['fno'];  
        echo "itm:".$itm." tval: ".$tval." t:".$t." appno:".$apno."fno:".$fno."<br/>";
      }
    }
?>
```

How can I correct this, so that it can display the correct id when the button is clicked after selecting.

Comment: what is the resulting ids when 777,895 and 901 are checked and clicked add to float?

Comment: @ArunKrish: it gives 773,774,775 respectively

Comment: ok the issue will be in the place where you loop and display the data in html table. The code you provided has not enough information on the loop  part. You need to check the query section and see whether the results get sorted based on 'id' when you click on Add to Float button when the page posts itself.

Comment: @ArunKrish: so, if that is not correct, Can you give a correct one or any link to solve this issue?

Comment: I think I have wrongly understood your question.. Do u want to remove the checked rows when u click Add to Float button?

Comment: @ArunKrish: I want to retrieve only the checked rows when the button is checked.In doing this, i need the partno, amount,id.all the fields are correctly returned but the id changes by turning to start id and increment it ascendingly instead of showing the fetched DB id.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120101/discussion-between-dave-and-arun-krish).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like this

```
<table>
  <tr>
 <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $r['item_code'];?>" name="itmcode[]"  readonly="readonly"/></td>
 <td><?php echo $r['description'];?></td>
 <td><?php echo $r['qty'];?></td>
 <td><?php echo $r['price_per_qty'];?>
 <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $r['total_value'];?>" name="tvalue[]" readonly="readonly" /></td>
 <td><?php echo $r['preferred_supplier'];?></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="chkbx[]"  value="<?php echo $r['id'];?>">

 //change gid[] to gid[<?php echo $r['id'];?>]

  <input type="hidden" name="gid[<?php echo $r['id'];?>]"  value="<?php echo $r['id'];?>">

  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

in processing

```
<?php
   if(array_key_exists('chkbx', $_POST)&&(!empty($_POST['chkbx']))&&   (isset($_POST['floatBtn']))){
foreach($_POST['chkbx'] as $rec=>$value)
  {
    $itm = $_POST['itmcode'][$rec];
    $tval = $_POST['tvalue'][$rec];

    $t = $_POST['gid'][$value]; //--> changed from $_POST['gid'][$rec] to $_POST['gid'][$value]

    $apno =$_POST['aNo']; 
    $fno = $_POST['fno'];  
    echo "itm:".$itm." tval: ".$tval." t:".$t." appno:".$apno."fno:".$fno."<br/>";
  }
}
 ?>
```

The issue when you post the data with the checkbox checked, you get an array like this

```
Array
(
  [itmcode] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1"
        [1] => 1"
        [2] => 1"
    )

[tvalue] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 5
        [2] => 5
    )

[chkbx] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
    )

[gid] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 3
    )
)
```

so when looping the $_POST['chkbx'], the value for 
   `$_POST['gid'][$rec] always loops with the keys of $_POST['chkbx'] which is 0,1,2 etc always. So you get values of $_POST['gid'][0], $_POST['gid'][1],$_POST['gid'][2], etc which is 773, 774, 775 respectively.